# Serializing JSON Object to be passed onto String Content not working, But String Literal works when sending POST Request(Error 400)

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-standard

I am trying to send a POST request to a web service. I am able to successfully do this in a console application, with a dummy request string literal. However, when I try to serialize my object using jsonConvert, and send that as the request, the server responds with a "400" Bad Request.

My String Literal:

```
            string invoiceRequest = @"{
""DateAndTimeOfIssue"": ""2017-06-15T08:56:23.286Z"",
""Cashier"": ""Oliver"",
""IT"": 3,
""TT"": 0,
""PaymentType"": ""Cash"",
""InvoiceNumber"": ""POS2017/998"",
""ReferentDocumentNumber"": ""ABCD1234-EFGH5678-198"",
""ReferentDocumentDateAndTime"": ""2017-06-07T09:33:52.187Z"",
""PAC"":""11111"",
    ""Options"":{
        ""OmitQRCodeGen"": ""1"",
        ""OmitTextualRepresentation"": ""1""},
     ""Items"": [{
        ""Name"": ""Sport-100 Helmet, Blue"",
        ""Quantity"": 2.0,
        ""UnitPrice"": 34.23,
        ""Labels"": [""A""],
        ""TotalAmount"": 68.46},
        {
        ""Name"": ""Sport-100 Helmet, Blue"",
        ""Quantity"": 2,
        ""UnitPrice"": 34.23,
        ""Labels"": [""A""],
        ""TotalAmount"": 68.46}],
""Hash"": ""W33lEEgkSRsqTFMO86a8Og==""}";
```

My Code:

```
    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(invoiceRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpClient client;
    HttpClientHandler handler;
    GetClientAndHandler(out handler, out client);
    var response = client.PostAsync($"api/Sign/SignInvoice", httpContent).Result;
```

The above works fine. However, now instead I would like to do this:

```
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent((JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this).ToString()), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

For some reason, the above does not work(even if I remove ToString()). Below is what I get when output JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this) to a file.

```
{
    "DataAndTimeOfIssue": "2017-06-15T08:56:23.286Z",
    "Cashier": "Kushal",
    "IT": "Training",
    "TT": "Sale",
    "PaymentType": "Cash",
    "InvoiceNumber": "POS2017/998",
    "ReferentDocumentNumber": "ABCD1234-EFGH5678-198",
    "ReferentDocumentDateAndTime": "2017-06-07T09:33:52.187Z",
    "PAC": "11111",
    "Options": {
        "OmitQRCodeGen": "1",
        "OmitTextualRepresentation": "0"
    },
    "Items": [{
        "GTIN": "Item 1",
        "Name": "Smokes",
        "Quantity": 3.0,
        "UnitPrice": 11.0,
        "Discount": 0.0,
        "Labels": ["A"],
        "TotalAmount": 30.0
    }, {
        "GTIN": "Item 2",
        "Name": "Smokes",
        "Quantity": 3.0,
        "UnitPrice": 0.0,
        "Discount": 0.0,
        "Labels": ["A"],
        "TotalAmount": 30.0
    }],
    "Hash": "W33lEEgkSRsqTFMO86a8Og=="
}
```

Grateful for any help on this. Thanks. Also, because of a solution design constraint, I have to use this, not anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your string literal you called the variable `DateAndTimeOfIssue`, but `DataAndTimeOfIssue` in the object. This might cause the error. Also, the type of the variable `IT` changes from a string to an interger. This shouldn't be a problem, because an int can be cast to a string, but I would suggest you, to use the same type.

Does the webservice support the variables `GTIN` and `Discount` in the `Items` array?

Comment: Thank you! It was infact the GTIN property, In the API Documents it says GTIN is supported, however the developer on their end did a change and did not update the docs! :(